# Fancybox iframe form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to open a fancybox iframe with HTML content inside for now It is just a simple html document with text but it will eventuallly be a form however when i click to test it, it simply opens up the other HTML document. how do I make it so that it opens up the html doc in an iframe. here is my html with the includes and button link that should open up the HTML in the fancybox:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css"     media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/source/vpb_script.js"></script>

<body>

<div id = "signup"><div><center><a class = "fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="form.html">      <img src="images/sign-up.png" width="216" height="65" /></a></center></div></div>

 </div>



</div>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
width : '70%',
height : '70%’
}); 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect single quote at the end of the height attribute.  You're using some sort of weird raised comma instead of a single quote and it's causing a javascript error.

See this fiddle where I've gotten it working.  http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/DRvyq/

html:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://disney.com">Iframe</a>
```

javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".fancybox").fancybox({
          width: '70%',
          height: '70%'
      });
  });
```